# How do I handle integer overflow while checking for armstrong numbers?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow

While solving a problem on exercism , I am failing the following test case:
Test Failure

```
thread 'properly_handles_overflow' panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow', src/lib.rs:9:9
```

```rust
use std::io;
pub fn is_armstrong_number(mut num: u32) -> bool {
    let check = num;
    let mut sum = 0;
    let length = (num as f64).log(10.0).floor() as u32 + 1;

    while num != 0 {
        let digit = num % 10;
        sum += u32::pow(digit, length);
        num = num / 10;
    }
    if sum == check {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input);
    let number: u32 = input.trim().parse().unwrap();

    is_armstrong_number(number);
}
```

Comment: (Formatting edit reverted so that line number in error message still relates to the correct line of code. OP, it makes it easier to read if the code is formatted to normal rust conventions (rustfmt defaults are a good starting point))

Comment: Please replace parsing of arbitrary user input with the number you actually passed when you found the error. You can read about that in the article on [mre]s

Comment: The only operation that can overflow is the addition in computing the some. Instead of using `+=`, you should use `checked_add()`, and return `false` on overflow.

Comment: Also note that there's s `log10()` function and that the last line of your function should be simply `sum == check` (without any `if` or `return`).